# Save a sheet in a workbook for every specific interval

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently working on a macro that forecasts years worth of data which I expect to run for long hours and even for several days. Given that, I plan to back up the forecasted data for every interval(30mins) so that if the run is interrupted, I would not need to start again from scratch, instead start from the last saved date.

What I plan to do is to autosave the sheet (of the .xlsm workbook) where the forecasted data is being inputed as a .xlsx file  every 30mins or any desired interval. And once the run is done, also terminate the autosave.

Thank you very much in advance for the help!

Comment: `Application.OnTime` should do what you need.

Comment: hi sir. thanks for this. is it possible to stop the application.ontime from re occuring once the main macro run is done?

Comment: You can clear the schedule as shown in the documentation